# Gridview not accepting dd.MM.yyyy value but after 1 update with MM.dd.yyyy it allows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.
I have a column type: date.
The column is itemtemplate

```
<asp:TextBox ID="IRR" runat="server" MaxLength="10" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("IRR", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Regional settings, date is set to format : `dd.MM.yyyy`

When I add a date value in gridview , in format `dd.MM.yyyy` I get error  :

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

But if I add a date value in format `MM.dd.yyyy` and if I edit the value again after update , it will allow `dd.MM.yyyy` value.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Check your sql server date time format.Because if your sql formate is MM.dd.yyyy then dd.MM.yyyy throw error

Comment: hmm I've checked in the database table column, I've added a value in format dd.MM.yyyy and I don't get any error .

Comment: verify your select query please. Provide your select query format. through which you bind your gridview.

Comment: Ah , I found where was the problem..the query was like Date=@Date but I've changed to convert(...) ..and it worked .

Answer (score 0):

@Jax: use following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```